# How to use output of select as input to function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function, select

I would like to use a function that I have in MySQL. This function is used to split a string, and takes the string, the delimiter and which element number I want to output based on the delimiter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
x VARCHAR(255),
delim VARCHAR(12),
pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
delim, '');
```

I can use the function in the following way:

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR('a:b', ':', 1);
```

which would output "a".

However, what would I have to do in order to use the output of the following MySQL command as the input string to my function?

```
select gene from enhancer limit 1;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need your own split string function in MySQL.  The function `substring_index()` is built-in.

If you want to pass a column to the string, you can do:

```
select substring_index(gene, ':', 1)
from enhancer
limit 1;
```

To get the nth value:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(gene, ':', <n>), ':', -1)
from enhancer
limit 1;
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much. This was very helpful! If I wanted to take the results of this product and put it in a newly created column in the same table as demonstrated here: http://puu.sh/ipDkr/e9bc64fc71.png . How would I be able to do this? Assuming I have an empty column I would like to put the results in.

Comment: @Vanquiza . . . You would use an `update` statement.  The string processing logic would be the same.  If this doesn't help, consider asking another question with sample data and desired results.